# return type mismatch in function declared to return posts

Tags: sql, postgresql

hello I have a query that passes to a psql function, to this I will pass 2 arguments lat and lng, the problem is that it should return an array of objects `[{id:..,distance:..},..]` I am using setof on return, should setof posts return to me?

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
  user_id uuid references auth.users not null,
  user_email text,
  title text,
  content text,
  latitude float,
  longitude float,
  created_at timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()) not null,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()) not null
);
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION near_places( lat float, lng float ) RETURNS SETOF posts AS $$

SELECT
    id,
    distance

FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            (
                3959 *
                acos(
                    cos( radians($1) ) *
                    cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
                    cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($2) ) +
                    sin( radians(-32.63) ) * 
                    sin( radians( latitude ) )
                )
            ) AS distance
        FROM
            posts
    ) p 

WHERE
    distance < 25

ORDER BY
    distance LIMIT 20

$$ language sql;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `posts`?

Comment: hello, The table name

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `posts`.

Comment: there it is, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `near_places` function returns 2 columns: `id, distance`, but your `posts` table has a completely different set of columns - so your function **does not** actually return a `SETOF posts` - it returns a custom table-type, [so change your DDL to `RETURNS TABLE()` which describes the `id, distance` columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION near_places( lat float, lng float )
RETURNS TABLE(
    id       int,
    distance real /* or decimal, numeric, etc */
) AS $$

SELECT
    id,
    distance

FROM
    /* etc */

$$ language sql;
```

Comment: thanks, if i want to return more info like title, description besides distance and id?

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic Then you need to add them to both the `RETURNS TABLE(...)` **and** the `SELECT` query.

Comment: i did it but returns me an error i.e "title" columns does not exist

Comment: Post a new, separate, SO question then.